# Firebase || read data from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the older version to read data from firestore

```
db.collection('cafes').get().then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(docs)
         });
     });
```

I think that's why I am getting db.collection() is not a function.

---

But from the present docs, it is like

```
async function getcafes(db) {
    const cafesCol = collection(db, 'cafes');
    const cafeSnapshot = await getDocs(cafesCol);
    const cafeList = cafeSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    console.log(cafeList)
    return cafeList;
}
```

So while using console.log(), it is not giving any output.

---

```
<head>
    <script type="module">
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
      import {
        getFirestore,
        collection,
        getDocs,
      } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js";
     

      const firebaseConfig = {
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const db = getFirestore(app);
      const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      window.db = db; // to make db global variable

      async function getcafes(db) {
        console.log('Fetching Cafes');        
        const cafesCol = collection(db, "cafes");
        const cafeSnapshot = await getDocs(cafesCol);
        const cafeList = cafeSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        console.log(cafeList);
        return cafeList;
      }

      getcafes() // calling the function

    </script>
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Can you add `console.log('Fetching cafes')` at the start of this function and check if the function is being called ?

Comment: Yes, it is printing Fetching data, but I need to call getcafes( ), and It triggers this error---                                                                                                                        
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: Can you share the code from where this function is being called? It doesn't seem like `db` is Firestore instance.

Comment: It should be `getcafes(db)`. Since that function is taking a param db, it'll read it's value rather than the global one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that within `getcafes()`, `db` is `undefined`, as `db` within the function is a local parameter. Try removing the `db` parameter from `getcafes` and allowing it to use the global `window.db`.

```javascript
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
window.db = db; // to make db global variable
// remove db parameter VV
async function getcafes() {
  console.log("Fetching Cafes");
  // now db here is the global database instead of undefined
  const cafesCol = collection(db, "cafes");
  const cafeSnapshot = await getDocs(cafesCol);
  const cafeList = cafeSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  console.log(cafeList);
  return cafeList;
}

getcafes(); // calling the function
```

Comment: If I want to use getcafes() in another script...should I do window.getcafes = getcafes...or there is another general method

Comment: Yeah, you could do that